# how to find heap memory of a iOS application in programatically?

Tags: java, ios, api, swift3, swift4

How to find out app specific heap memory of a iOS application in swift?

Is there any possible way to find out heap memory using app id, or any API.I have tried to find out using below code but it is not matching with the Xcode instrument result.

```
func memoryFootprint() -> mach_vm_size_t? {
    let TASK_VM_INFO_COUNT = mach_msg_type_number_t(MemoryLayout<task_vm_info_data_t>.size / MemoryLayout<integer_t>.size)
    let TASK_VM_INFO_REV1_COUNT = mach_msg_type_number_t(MemoryLayout.offset(of: \task_vm_info_data_t.min_address)! / MemoryLayout<integer_t>.size)
    var info = task_vm_info_data_t()
    var count = TASK_VM_INFO_COUNT
    let kr = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &info) { infoPtr in
        infoPtr.withMemoryRebound(to: integer_t.self, capacity: Int(count)) { intPtr in
            task_info(mach_task_self_, task_flavor_t(TASK_VM_INFO), intPtr, &count)
        }
    }
    guard
        kr == KERN_SUCCESS,
        count >= TASK_VM_INFO_REV1_COUNT
        else { return nil }
    print((Double(info.internal)/Double(info.page_size))/1024)
    print((Double(info.resident_size)/Double(info.page_size))/1024)
    print((Double(info.phys_footprint)/Double(info.page_size))/1024)

    return info.phys_footprint
}
```